# Use Object.create and toString.call() to return '[object Rectangle]'

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

In node: if I do

```
var Shape = {
  x:0,
  y:0
}

var rectangle = Object.create(Shape);
```

I can get:

```
toString.call(rectangle);
//'[object Object]'
toString.call(Shape);
//'[object Object]'
toString.call({});
//'[object Object]'
```

Is there a way to effect something like:

```
toString.call(rectangle);
'[object Shape]'
```

I'm aware that I could override Shape.toString() or create a new Shape.toClassString() method but I'm interested in the toString.call() implementation. Is this a v8-necessary issue?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? There is no good reason.

Comment: Intellectual curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at the specification: http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.2.

Basically, the default implementation takes the internal `[[Class]]` property and concatenates it to the resulting string. Since both `Shape` and `rectangle` are plain objects, their internal `[[Class]]` property is `Object`. You have to override `toString` or create the object with a constructor function.

I don't think V8 or Node.js give you any additional possibilities to override this, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: I'm sure you can patch Node.js to add another custom host object with odd [[Class]] values…

Comment: @Bergi: I can also write my own JS engine and do this... (at least theoretically) ;)

Comment: Thanks, I checked out the ES6 Draft and it seems like toString() is going to support the current objects '[object Object]', but not necessarily the new ones, such as TypedArray, which may come out as '[object Array]' because of the [[BuiltinBrand]] values.